# Performance -- check for no rows or just perform *multiple* update statements?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that updates 2 separate tables based on 1 condition.  In order to avoid a race condition, I am first recording the primary key of the rows that need to be updated in a temp table and then updating that table plus another table (foreign key reference) from that temp table.

Over 99% of the time that this is run there will be 0 rows to update.  Thus from a performance perspective I'd like to know if it would be worth checking for any rows before performing updates on no rows.

```
select distinct matters
into #matters_t
from mattersqdefaultprocess
where reopen is not null
   and reopen = 'Y'

update m
set status = 'Open'
from matters m
inner join #matters_t mu on mu.matters = m.matters
where m.status in ('inactive', 'closed')

update mdp
set reopen = 'N'
from mattersqdefaultprocess mdp
inner join #matters_t mu on mu.matters = mdp.matters
```

It seems logical to me that it would be beneficial to check for no rows if there are, say 50 update statements.  For only 2?  That is the question, I suppose.

Perhaps I should just do this:

```
if 0 < (select count(*)
        from mattersqdefaultprocess mdp
        where qdefprocreopen is not null
           and qdefprocreopen = 'Y')
   begin
      --do the temp table seeding and updates here
   end
```

Comment: Inspect the execution plan for the case when there are no rows to evaluate and compare that to the check you are considering adding. If the check takes less time to run then its beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general absence of any answers or discussion, I went ahead and set it up with the `if` statement and everything (including creating temp tables) else inside the `true` part of the `if` statement.